# How to avoid gap on top of UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

As shown in this image Im facing issue with UIPickerView.There is gap at the top as you can see.I wnat to remove that gap.Anyone know the solution for this.Any help is much appreciated.Thank you in advance

[image: in this image]

Comment: How about setting third element on selection by default? Cause, whatever you set the frame of PickerView; for the very first element, it will show the blank space on the top of it.

Comment: Yup that is my problem.When I scroll back to row 0 the gap shows up.I think it is a default behavior.There is no way to avoid it.@Matt

Comment: Yeah, same as when you select the last one, the empty space is at the bottom of PickerView.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli did you get the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :-

```
[Picker addTarget:self action:@selectorAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIView *view = [[Picker subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[[view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:YES];
    [[[view subviews] lastObject] setHidden:YES];
```

You can add the picker to a view and make a subview out of it .

Comment: Application is getting crashed with sigabrt.I have added picker in an action sheet

Answer (score 0):

There is a only way to avoid gap top of UIPickerView

Change the frame of a picker. Like this.

```
smallerPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
smallerPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 165.0)
```

OR

```
smallerPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, 0.5);
```

like change the scale of picker

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about my solution.

Comment: My question is not about changing frame of pickerView.AnyWays thanks for responding @OhSeungKwon

Comment: Sorry :( I did not mean to bother you. But there's no way to avoid gap without changing your frame.

Comment: Changing frame also not solving my problem.Thank you